# in java, how do I loop a section of code again?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a text based game in java, and I want to be able to print the players stats at anytime. The way the game works is you have numbered options to make choices, and you type in the number of the choice you want. However, if you type 99, it prints out your stats. But after that, you can't actually make the choice. It just prints out the stats, and moves on in the code. How would I get it to start over that loop so the player can make the choice and ask for stats?

Here's the code:

```
        if(one = true){//I want to start here again if you type in 99.
            int weaponchoice;
            weaponchoice = scan.nextInt();
            if(weaponchoice == 1){
                strength = 3;
                agility = 2;
                stealth = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Fusion Heated Shotgun";
                System.out.println(">New Weapon equiped.< ");
                System.out.println(">strength + 2, agility + 1, stealth - 1.< ");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(">The weapon chache locks up.<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                one = false;
                two = true;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 2){
                accuracy = 3;
                strength = 2;
                agility = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "High Impact Ballistic Sniper Rifle";
                System.out.println(">New Weapon equipped<");
                System.out.println(">Accuracy + 2, Strength + 1, Agility - 1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(">The weapon cache locks up<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                one = false;
                two = true;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 3){
                stealth = 3;
                agility = 2;
                strength = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Silenced Lazer Pistol";
                System.out.println(">New weapon equipped.< ");
                System.out.println(">Stealth + 2, Agility + 1, Strength - 1<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                one = false;
                two = true;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 4){
                agility = 2;
                accuracy = 2;
                stealth = 2;
                strength = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Multi Purpose Combat Knife";
                System.out.println(">You pick up the weapon.<");
                System.out.println(">agility + 1. Accuracy + 1. Stealth + 1. Strength - 1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                one = false;
                two = true;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 5){
                agility = 3;
                strength = 2;
                stealth = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Lazer Katana";
                System.out.println(">You pick up the weapon.<");
                System.out.println(">Agility +2. Stength +1. Stealth -1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                one = false;
                two = true;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 99){
                System.out.println("Health: " + health);
                System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
                System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
                System.out.println("Accuracy " + accuracy);
                System.out.println("Stealth " + stealth);
                //so my question is really how do I from here all the way back to the beginning of the code I've shown. 
            }
```

Comment: **How would I get it to start over that loop so the player can make the choice and ask for stats?** You are answering the question itself. Try to do some research about for loops and while loops.

Comment: You should double (or tripple) check this line: `if(one = true)`.

Comment: Put that code inside while loop - while(true) {} or a condition which will help looping. It will keep on repeating...

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop

```
while (true){//I want to start here again if you type in 99.
            int weaponchoice;
            weaponchoice = scan.nextInt();
            if(weaponchoice == 1){
                strength = 3;
                agility = 2;
                stealth = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Fusion Heated Shotgun";
                System.out.println(">New Weapon equiped.< ");
                System.out.println(">strength + 2, agility + 1, stealth - 1.< ");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(">The weapon chache locks up.<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                break;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 2){
                accuracy = 3;
                strength = 2;
                agility = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "High Impact Ballistic Sniper Rifle";
                System.out.println(">New Weapon equipped<");
                System.out.println(">Accuracy + 2, Strength + 1, Agility - 1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(">The weapon cache locks up<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                break;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 3){
                stealth = 3;
                agility = 2;
                strength = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Silenced Lazer Pistol";
                System.out.println(">New weapon equipped.< ");
                System.out.println(">Stealth + 2, Agility + 1, Strength - 1<");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                break;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 4){
                agility = 2;
                accuracy = 2;
                stealth = 2;
                strength = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Multi Purpose Combat Knife";
                System.out.println(">You pick up the weapon.<");
                System.out.println(">agility + 1. Accuracy + 1. Stealth + 1. Strength - 1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                break;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 5){
                agility = 3;
                strength = 2;
                stealth = 0;
                weaponslot[0] = "Lazer Katana";
                System.out.println(">You pick up the weapon.<");
                System.out.println(">Agility +2. Stength +1. Stealth -1<");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("''What should I do now?'', you think to yourself.''");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To go to the Hangar, press 1");
                System.out.println("To leave the ship, leave the military, and go home, press 2.");
                System.out.println("To explore the ship, press 3");
                break;
            }
            if(weaponchoice == 99){
                System.out.println("Health: " + health);
                System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
                System.out.println("Agility: " + agility);
                System.out.println("Accuracy " + accuracy);
                System.out.println("Stealth " + stealth);
                //so my question is really how do I from here all the way back to the beginning of the code I've shown. 
            } 
        }
```